# Using Dplyr to encode multiple levels within a group

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I'm trying to encode a column for my dataset if there is more than one level once the data has been grouped down by a couple factors. For simplicity I am using the mtcars data set as an example. I keep getting the error "Error: filter condition does not evaluate to a logical vector. "

Clearly this syntax isn't acceptable, but does anyone have a more clever way of doing this?

```
 df_levels <-  mtcars %>%
   group_by(mpg) %>%
   filter(nlevels(.$gear) > 1) %>%
   mutate(Levels = 1) ##encode with a boolean value indicating more than one level
```

and

```
 df_levels <-  df_levels %>%
   group_by(mpg) %>%
   filter(nlevels(.$gear) < 1) %>%
   mutate(Levels = 0)
```

So if you click on the new df  "df_levels", and sort by mpg in the df viewer, you would see a column "levels" = 0 for entries with 10.4 mpg (because there is only data with gear = 3), and the column "levels" associated with 30.4 mpg would have value = 1 because there is more than one level for gear in that data grouping (gear = 4, gear = 5).

Comment: str(mtcars$gear)
 num [1:32] 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(Levels = ifelse(nlevels(as.factor(gear)) > 1, 1, 0))
```

Comment: Still not sure this is working.. say you group by mpg, and are concerned with the nlevels of gear.  You would expect the new DF to have value '0' in column Levels for the 10.4 mpg entries, and value '1' for the 30.4 mpg entries. I think @BryanGoggin has the same issue.

Comment: Can you may be clarify what your expected output is by editing the question?

Comment: @jacobOdom, if you switch the group to mpg, you will get exactly the results you suggested. Here's the code: `mtcars %>%
  group_by(mpg) %>%
  mutate(Levels = ifelse(nlevels(as.factor(gear)) > 1, 1, 0))`

Comment: @Edward Not sure what I was messing up when I ran this the first time. I cleared the variables and got it to work. Thanks for your help & patience!

Answer (score 1):

The variable `gear` in `mtcars` is not a factor, so I think you mean

```
mtcars$gear<-as.factor(mtcars$gear)
```

Then, try this:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  filter(nlevels(.$gear) > 1) %>%
  mutate(Levels = 1)
```

I am not sure by your question if this is what you're after, but at least it does not return an error.

And to be clear, the `dplyr` syntax is such that you could very cleanly do

```
mtcars %>%
group_by(cyl) %>%
filter(nlevels(gear) > 1) %>%
mutate(Levels = 1)
```

Comment: Still not sure this is working.. say you group by mpg, and are concerned with the nlevels of gear.  You would expect the new DF to have value '0' in column Levels for the 10.4 mpg entries, and value '1' for the 30.4 mpg entries.

Comment: My apologies, I did not understand what you were trying to do. I just fixed your original syntax. I am glad @Edward R. Mazurek was able to help.